# How do i get docx2txt to process all docx files in directory?

Tags: python, docx

I'm using the docx2txt module in python2.7 and I'm trying to get it to process all of the docx files in one directory. Currently I have doc2txt.process("THE NAME OF THE DOCUMENT.docx")

I want to process all docx files in the current working directory but I'm not sure how to do that

I have inserted my code below. It prints out the name of the file and the text in the docx file.

```
import os
import docx2txt

os.chdir('c:/users/Says/desktop')

files = []

path = 'c:/users/Says/desktop'



my_text = docx2txt.process("test.docx")

for files in os.listdir(path):
    if files.endswith('docx'):
        print(files)
        print(my_text)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I eventually want to create a search function. So the user can input a word and then the python script will read all docx files in a directory and tell me which files have that word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're half way there.

Create a list to store all the files that you find:

```
files = []
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.docx'):
        files.append(file)
```

Then you can use a `for` statement to loop through all the files and open them one at a time:

```
for i in range(len(files)):
    text = docx2txt.process(files[i])
    # Do something with the text.
```

If you want to change your code to allow the use of the current working directory you can set your path to:

```
path = os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to add code to the 'do something with the text part' but I seem to either be getting 'process finished with exit code 0' or an empty list '[]' as output

Comment: How you process the files is up to you. What you asked was how to get the text from the files - which my answer shows you. If you get an empty list, then you have no files that end with '.docx' in your specified path. 
On another note, it really sounds like you want to start exploring keyword arguments or gui's in order to pass a word to your program that you can then use to process your files.

Comment: And process finished just means python has finished executing your script and has nothing left to do, so it stops running. In which case if you want to keep the interpreter open after the script is complete you could run `python -i file.py` (https://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/keep_open.html)

Comment: Thanks @Ninetails :)